# Ford Fusion ABS Pump Selection

Tags: ford, abs, fusion

I have a 2009 FWD Ford Fusion SEL with AdvanceTrac. The HCU/ABS Pump is having an issue that is apparently decently common with these cars, where a valve in the HCU gets stuck open after the ABS is activated, greatly reducing break pressure. As far as I've been able to determine, this means I need to replace the part.

While searching for parts, I've found two that ostensibly match my vehicle, depending on where I'm searching. The parts, on fordparts.com, are these:

[9E5Z-2C215-A](http://www.fordparts.com/Commerce/PartDetail.aspx?n=t5AwAjxDOgctjGSMD5F4Ig%3D%3D&id=399537899&m=2&search=true&year=2009&make=Ford&model=Fusion) - ABS Control Unit Traction Control With Advance Trac (MSRP ~$1350, available for ~$1100). Searching by VIN on fordparts.com indicates I need this part.

and

[6E5Z-2C215-A](http://www.fordparts.com/Commerce/PartDetail.aspx?n=XlXGM8dFanqi6RTvydavyg%3D%3D&id=399641607&m=2&search=true&year=2009&make=Ford&model=Fusion) - ABS Control Unit With Brake Only Traction Control, Less Traction Control, Traction Control W/O Advance Trac (MSRP ~$850, available for ~$600). Just about every other site says I need this part.

Ideally, I'd like to purchase the second part, because its cost is about half of the former, but I have the following questions:

1) Given that the rest of the applicable parts in my car support/use AdvanceTrac, is the non-AdvanceTrac part going to even interoperate with the rest of the system, or do all of the parts need to match exactly?

2) Assuming I can use the second part, what, exactly, do I lose going from using AdvanceTrac to "Brake Only Traction Control, Less Traction Control"?

3) For bonus points, what exactly is the difference between these two pumps? I can understand why there might be a different in, say, the 2c219 part (the computer side of the thing) in terms of handling AdvanceTrac, but what would need to be different in the pump?

---

As an aside, I don't understand how this fault hasn't been recalled. I feel like a defect that can cause significant and sudden reduction in breaking power is a rather huge safety issue. :|

Comment: From the meta site: "Specifically, asking questions about the costs of repairs or parts, where to find parts, and the like are not good questions." Note that I'm not asking about the costs; I have the costs - they're included in the question only to motivate *why* I'm asking about these specific parts. The questions I'm asking are technical and aren't asking about anything cost-related.

The "bonus points" bit is a way to say "it would be nice if this question was answered, but it's not completely relevant to my goals". If it should be removed or reworded or something, I can do that.

Comment: As for the part numbers, it seems that Ford parts (and maybe all car parts, I'm not sure) are numbered very similarly, and the fordparts.com site only shows a partial number (the 2c215 shown on the site) that indicates the type of part, but not the exact piece. The full part numbers are actually different in the first digit, but for some reason Ford doesn't want to actually show them.

Comment: I'm not seeing this as shopping assistance, but rather as wondering which part should or can be used and what's the difference between the parts listed. Nothing about shopping, but about ensuring the proper part is being looked at prior to purchase. Seems like a smart question to ask to me.

Comment: If Paulster2 says it is not off-topic, I'm good with that. It is my fault since I am still struggling with some of these SE sites being more strict than others about their guidelines.

Comment: I'll leave this as a comment, you want the 9e5z-2c215-a part the 6e5z part is for normal traction control systems. I'd suspect that the 6e5z would continuously throw codes or not work at all if the wiring is different. I'll look into it a bit later.

Comment: @CharlieRB - This is just my opinion. If the Mech.SE community at large says it's off-topic, then so beit, I'm not going to argue with that. I'm just posting up my thinking and how I see it. I could, as a mod, dismiss the close votes and keep it open, but you'll notice I didn't do that. I'm still learning how to be a Mod yet as well, which is to say I'm not infallible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they need to match exactly. The two part numbers are not interchangeable.

The mechanical difference between the two is in the Brake Pressure Modulator Valve.

- The 6E5Z-2C215-AA (w/o AdvanceTrac) is a 3 circuit setup. The BPMV can send fluid to the left front, right front and combined rear wheels. It contains 3 dump/isolation valves, the pump, pump motor and the front/rear low pressure accumulators.
- The 9E5Z-2C215-AA (w/AdvanceTrac) is a 4 circuit setup. The BPMV can send fluid to all 4 wheels independently. It contains, the pump, pump motor, 4 dump/isolation valves, 2 TC isolation/supply valves, a master cylinder pressure sensor and the front/rear low pressure accumulators.

Also note that AdvanceTrac is Ford's version of Electronic Stability Control. So it contains and takes input from other (Some are the same, WSS) sensors than the w/o AdvanceTrac module does.

As an aside, if you plan on doing the work yourself make sure you have a way to pulse the BPMV during bleeding.